# The Zarankiewics Problem for $K_{2,2}$. Upper bound.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This problem has proved to give me a lot of trouble.
Please provide a complete solution for me.

Find the Upper Bound for $ex(n, K_{2,2}) = \Omega(n^\frac{3}{2})$ edges.

We say $f(n) = \sigma(g(n))$ if $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$

I am sorry I cannot provide more details. I am new to grasping this subject.

Comment: If you can't tell us what $ex(n,K_{2,2})$ means, how do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: For a graph $H$ the Turan number $ex(H,n)$ is the maximum number of edges that a graph on $n$ vertices can have without containing a copy of $H$

Comment: Good. Please edit that into the body of the question. Oh, and try to be consistent as to whether you write $ex({\rm number},{\rm graph})$ or $ex({\rm graph},{\rm number})$.

Comment: What's the source of the problem, please?

Comment: Please engage with the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good source that I found: [Zarankiewics Link](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~asafico/ext-graph-theory/notes.pdf)!

There is a proof for ex(n, K<sub>2,2</sub> ) = $O(n^\frac{3}{2})$